# Field identification, during except() operation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, except

`except()` function in spark work to compare two dataframes and return non matching records from first dataframe.

however, I would like to track field details also, which are not matching. how to do it in spark ?? please help

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned except will give you complete row mismatch. So I would suggest use leftanti join instead of except and have a join key or keys as condition. Primary or composite keys you can take. This will give you row mismatch w.r.t those keys. Then you need to write one more query where your keys matched I.e intersection but any mismatches in other columns. Write an inner join for this w.r.t keys where table1.colA != table2.colA like this for all fields in case condition.